# How to add space to the bottom of the chart in chartjs [angular]

Tags: css, angular, typescript, chart.js

HI all I have build a chart visualization using chartjs library

my code : [Example I have developed](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-legend-with-value-hide-kvcuos)

using this piece of code I can add space on the top of the chart but I want a solution to add space at the bottom of the chart.

code I used

```
public doughnutChartPlugin = [
        {
            beforeInit: function (chart, options) {
                chart.legend.afterFit = function () {
                    this.height += 30;
                };
            }
        }
    ];
```

I have attached a screenshot : [image: screenshot]

please help me with a solution

Comment: just add margin-top:30px on second div tag and you are good to go.And let me know if it helps.

Comment: not working @KrunalShah

Comment: i have tried in your stackblitz and its working... Check it out - https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-demo-example-naveen-kla8qp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add padding in chart layout so that chart can get space to display label.

```
options:{
  layout: {
    padding: {
      left: 30,
      right: 30,
      top: 30,
      bottom: 30
    }
  },
}
```